# Is it possible to create a REUSABLE invocable method for serializing Apex Defined Variables (Wrappers) to be used in flows?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, json, invocable-method, serialization

Edit: I've tried this by creating virtual/abstract class and setting it as the parameter for the invocable and then made an extension and passed it from the flow. Flow doesn't seem to allow this, it only accepts the base virtual/abstract classes and not the extensions. Also generic `Object` are not allowed as parameters for invocable methods and as invocable variables.

I've seen a similar implementation for Generic SObjects, but wondering if there's a way to to this for Wrappers.
https://unofficialsf.com/pass-objects-to-flow-via-rest-with-the-serializedeserialize-collection-actions/

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize/serialize any class you want. Just create a Wrapper class and then:

```
String wrapperString = System.JSON.serialize(wrapperItem);
Wrapper myWrapper = (Wrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(wrapperString , Wrapper.class);
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserialize

Comment: N.B. some types are unserializable (`SobjectField`, `SObjectType`, ...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was actually thinking whether it's possible to make it reusable. Right now, from the flow can only pass the exact same wrapper I've set as the parameter on the invocable method. I've tried creating an abstract/virtual class then set it as the parameter and created extensions of that class, but still on flows it only accepts the base abstract/virtual class.